# Unable to find procedure in DBA_PROCEDURES view

Tags: oracle, view, oracle11g, metadata, procedure

I have created a procedure :

```
create or replace procedure gg as
begin
insert into book values ('prashant','prashant','prashant');
commit;
end;
/
```

Procedure has been created successfully.Now i want to check the package name for the corresponding procedure but i am not able to do so.

I am using the below query :

```
 > SELECT *
        FROM SYS.DBA_PROCEDURES
        WHERE procedure_name ='gg';
```

Its giving 0 rows selected.Please help.

Comment: Actually the issue is that you need to use `object_name` instead of `procedure_name` since it is a stand alone procedure.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** Please look at the UPDATE section for correct answer.

The procedure name cannot be in lower case in the DBA_PROCEDURES view. Use upper case, or apply UPPER function.

```
SELECT *
  FROM SYS.DBA_PROCEDURES
 WHERE procedure_name ='GG';
```

**UPDATE**

The only case when you could have the name in lower case is if you enclose it within double-quotation marks while compiling.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE "p"
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5    NULL;
  6  END;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> SELECT object_name, procedure_name, object_type FROM user_procedures where procedure_name='p';

no rows selected

SQL>
```

But still the above view will not return any result for **PROCEDURE_NAME**.

**Reason**

**PROCEDURE_NAME** column will only have the procedure name for the procedures which are part of a **PACKAGE**. For **STAND ALONE PROCEDURES** you need to use **OBJECT_NAME**.

```
SQL> -- stand alone procedure in lower case
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE "p"
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5    NULL;
  6  END;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL>  -- package
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PACKAGE test_p
  3  IS
  4    PROCEDURE p;
  5  END test_p;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> -- package body with a procedure
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PACKAGE BODY test_p
  3  IS
  4  PROCEDURE p
  5  IS
  6  BEGIN
  7    NULL;
  8  END;
  9  END test_p;
 10  /

Package body created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT object_name, procedure_name, object_type FROM user_procedures;

OBJECT_NAME     PROCEDURE_NAME  OBJECT_TYPE
--------------- --------------- ---------------
TEST_P          P               PACKAGE
p                               PROCEDURE
TEST_P                          PACKAGE

SQL>
```

So, as you can see, the `procedure_name` is only having the `package's procedure`, however the `stand-alone procedure` is only listed under `object_name`.

Comment: well, it *can* be lowercase, but in this case it is not.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Lower case could be only if the name was enclosed within double quotation marks, however in OP's case it isn't the case. I think I should add this bit in the answer too.

Comment: Anyway, the issue is that the `procedure_name` column will be NULL for stand alone procedures

Answer (score 0):

The query I use is:

```
SELECT * FROM User_Procedures WHERE NVL(Procedure_Name,Object_Name) = 'PROCNAME';
```