# How to get a list of all user-created stored procedures and functions in a specific schema of Oracle 9i?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have some user-created stored procedures and functions in this legacy database. How do I list all procedures and functions of one specific schema, let's say, SCHEMA1, for instance.

Comment: Depends on the objects you want to see in your list. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema and user are somewhat synonymous in Oracle.

If you want to list down all the procedures and functions in a specific schema, then query:

1. **user_objects** : If you are logged in as the user you want to query the object list.
2. **all_objects** : You need to filter with **OWNER**.

For example,

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_objects
 WHERE object_type 
   IN('FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE');
```

Or,

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE 
   IN ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE')
AND OWNER = 'your_schema_name';
```

Make sure you pass the required values in upper case.

**UPDATE**

From documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2025.htm,

> ALL_PROCEDURES
>
> ALL_PROCEDURES lists all functions and procedures, along with
>   associated properties. For example, ALL_PROCEDURES indicates whether
>   or not a function is pipelined, parallel enabled or an aggregate
>   function. If a function is pipelined or an aggregate function, the
>   associated implementation type (if any) is also identified.

So, you could also use **user_procedures** view as per documentation.

**NOTE**

Please note few things regarding `*_procedures`. You need to take care whether the procedure is standalone or whether is wrapped within a package. I have written an article based on the same here [Unable to find procedure in DBA_PROCEDURES view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343972/unable-to-find-procedure-in-dba-procedures-view)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look up the list of all procedures then -

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_PROCEDURES WHERE OWNER = 'SCHEMA1';
```

This of course assumes that you have permissions to see the procedures/functions/packages of SCHEMA1.

If however you have the DBA privilege, then you can also do -

```
SELECT * from DBA_PROCEDURES WHERE OWNER = 'SCHEMA1';
```

If you want the code inside the procedures then look up ALL_SOURCE or DBA_SOURCE.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to receive this information:

1. Log in as `SYSDBA`
2. Query `dba_source`

SQL:

```
select distinct NAME from dba_source
where  TYPE in ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE')
and    OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAME';
```